# Script that removes all occurences of duplicated lines from file + keeps the original order of lines (perl + python + lua)

Tags: scripting

As the title says, i need to make a script in perl, one in python and one in lua that removes all occurences of a duplicate line (*can be even a one-line command*). For example let's say the file has the following lines (I don't know exactly what the file has, need a generic command to do that, this is just an example):

```
apple
orange
banana
banana
berry
cherry
orange
melon
```

The output should be like :

```
apple
berry
cherry
melon
```

Another thing to note is that i need the file to ***have the same line order as it was at the beginning***. I managed to pull multiple commands using `awk` and `sed`, but i couldn't find anything related to removing ***all occurences*** in `python` / `lua` / `perl`.

Comment: Please add your tries

Comment: In Lua, why not use a table such as `t={}` then `t["apple"]=t["apple"]+1` you will both get unique keys and the number of occurrences.

Comment: Because i need to extract any duplicated lines  considering i don't know what's in the file, so i can't target a specific word or line, need a generic one @macroland

Comment: You dont need to know, `t["apple"]` was just a conceptual demo. You can say `t[string]` as you read the strings.

Comment: Oh i see, apologies for misunderstanding then

Comment: So it works as `t[line]` aswell to check line by line ? or it works only on strings @macroland

Comment: As long as you refer to the entry as `t[line]` and not `t.line` it will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Perl, you'd keep a hash to record what you've already seen.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;

while (<>) {
  print unless $seen{$_}++;
}
```

This reads from `STDIN` and writes to `STDOUT`, so you can use it as a Unix filter. If it's in a file called `filter`:

```
$ filter < input_data > filtered_data
```

**Update:** Ok, I misunderstood the requirement. You can't do this without iterating across the data twice. Here's a Perl solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @data;
my %count;

# Store the input data and also
# keep a count.
while (<>) {
  $count{$_}++;
  push @data, $_;
}

# Print the input data, but only
# records which only appear once.
print grep { $count{$_} == 1 } @data;
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP wants. This skips the duplicates, but the OP wants to skip lines that have duplicates. For example, this will print "orange", but the OP wants to skip "orange" as there is a duplicate for it.

Comment: Yeah, need to completely skip all the duplicated lines

Comment: @JonBjatBun: My update contains a correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

In python you can just use the following script.

```py
    file = open("myfile.txt", "r")
    no_duplicates = list(dict.fromkeys(file.readlines())
```

- `readlines()` returns an ordered list of the file content. Each line gives a list item.
- `dict.fromkeys(a)` generates a dict for the list of key `a`. It reads the list in order, and doesn't add already existing keys.

Comment: This answer is not the ideal solution. The code is OK but not really efficient though.  First, your list could be constructed with a comprehension generator (much faster). Secondly, buffers have a method called `readlines()` that returns immediately each line of the buffer into a list of string. So, finally, constructing the list is a waste of time, line and memory.

Comment: @NiborNdj totally agree, I updated. Thank you

Comment: I have added some details to explain the meaning of your code.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for that one... here the crt code in python....

```
x=open("dupli","r")
ar=(x.readlines())
new=[]
for i in ar:
    co=ar.count(i)
    if co == 1:
        new.append(i)
print(new)
```

the result will be..

```
['apple\n', 'berry\n', 'cherry\n', 'melon\n']
```

Comment: have you checked the output i put above ?

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm of the code

> walk through the data
>
> `++$count{$_}` occurrences of word
>
> store word in an array `@words` only if seen for first time (to preserve words order)
>
> use array `@words` to output word only if it's `$count{$_} == 1`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %count;
my @words;

for( <DATA> ) {
    ++$count{$_} == 1 && push @words, $_;
}

$count{$_} == 1 && print for @words;

__DATA__
apple
orange
banana
banana
berry
cherry
orange
melon
```

Output

```
apple
berry
cherry
melon
```